# Is calculus background a must for learn DSP?

Tags: continuous-signals, digital-filters, analog

I'm beginner in DSP and in the literature some Authors suggest Analog (Continuous) Signal Processing a prerequisite for learn DSP. But it demands calculus background, that I do not have. Is calculus and ASP background a must for learn DSP?

Comment: Short answer - you might get away without it, but it is going to be a huge handicap.

Comment: Mr jojek, I asked meta.exchange.com for show me the way to get away, but did not show me that. Just they awarded me with their "informed" award. So only way for me to get away from here is the way you  got away from Vietnam. By helicopter. Regards.

Comment: Although short question (answer is following), is essential for learn DSP. One, just high school graduate (as is my case), if, indeed, has learned what has been taught, can learn DSP from websites, like this, and books online accessed by Google books. Regards.

Comment: Mr jojek, I asked just the specialists in DSP, opinion. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

With Google's search engine and Google books, I investigated that someone, without calculus background, can learn DSP. I expected learn from you that for avoid laborious searching. I'm very sorry for did not learn that from you. Regards.

Comment: In later investigation I found at this site in Mr Matt L.'s answer to question by Mr Michael Choi, "Bandpass General Equation to Difference Equation" that for understand the transfer function of a digital second-order band-pass filter, I have to accept without proof the corresponding continuous function, because proof is not published even by the rigorous Wikipedia.

Comment: Why not asking it here (the best place on Earth to ask it!)? Like how to find the continuous time Laplace Transform of a Lowpass, Highpass, Bandpass, Bandstop etc filter transfer function $H(s)$. You better ask them separately one by one. Then you will have what you need.

Comment: Mr Fat32, awaiting helicopter I ask it here. Regards.

Comment: Ladies Gentlemen, let me say that in my dear dsp Teacher, he teaches me through his book, Mr. Richard Lyons's book "Understanding DSP", I found what is and what is not a must for learning the fundamentals - just what I need - of DSP: "it does not require profound analytical skills or an extensive background in mathematics. All you need is a little experience with elementary algebra, knowledge of what a sinewave is, this book, and enthusiasm" (first phrase of preface). Regards.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou , Dear Sir, I've read your posts and comments. I think you are right that profound knowledge of math is not necessary for prcatical (not academic) signal processing. I have suggestion for you. I suggest you to use interactive online DSP tools, which perform a huge amount of math and design consideration for you and also helps you to digest DSP materials more intuitively. Here is a great tool    http://www.micromodeler.com/dsp/ .             Regards

Comment: @MimSaad: Please accept my many thanks for your comment. I'm aware of this site. However I need some theoretical background for understand and use these tools. Regards.

Comment: You'r welcomed Sir.

Comment: @ MimSaad: Please accept my many thanks for your welcome. I have to post many questions here on the topic "low-pass FIR filter" especially on how its features (sample rate, segment, cut-off zone, taps) affect output samples accuracy. For the time being I learn DFT. Regards.